# QT 5.9.2 --> 5.10.0 application styles lost?

Tags: c++, qt

We recently upgraded the version of Qt we use in a desktop application from Qt 5.9.2 to 5.10.0.  On startup it suddenly looked terrible.

Playing around with application styles (i.e. Looking at the return value of "QStyleFactory::keys()" which I might supply to "QApplication::setStyle()" ), I discovered that whereas 5.9.2 gave us 4 styles right out of the box, 5.10.0 gives us only 2.

5.9.2 gave us these:

- "Windows"
- "WindowsXP"
- "WindowsVista"
- "Fusion"

However 5.10.0 only gives us "Windows" and "Fusion".  By default it is now apparently choosing "Windows" when before it was choosing "WindowsVista" so it looks terrible.

Anyone out there familiar enough with Qt to tell me how I might get "WindowsVista" again in 5.10.0?  Has it perhaps moved to some other DLL that we're failing to copy?  Has it been removed?

(Note: We do not not build Qt ourselves, we use the installer.  I don't see any sort of option in there for choosing additional styles" or anything like that...)

Comment: Check this link : https://forum.qt.io/topic/86777/missing-qapplication-styles-in-qt-5-10-0/2

Comment: Thanks.  Actually that is also my thread.  Just tried here for maximum coverage.

Comment: Did you somehow resolve the problem? I'm facing similar situation.

Comment: One thing I did was give the user the ability to choose, in preferences, which style to use. I present them with a dialog which show a list of the results of QStyleFactory::Keys.  Looking at my application now (which is still using 5.10.0) I see "windowsvista", "Windows" and "Fusion".    The WindowsXP style is gone, but I admittedly was wrong above about there only being "Windows" and "Fusion"

Basically if the user has not configured anything, my code first tries to use windowsvista, then fusion

Comment: Also if you see in that other referenced thread, I did a complete uninstall and reinstall of Qt to make sure I got all 3 styles.  But still, no XP style anymore

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually figure this out and since someone asked (in the comments) what the resolution was, I'll answer my own question.

First of all I had to uninstall and completely reinstall Qt 5.10.0.  I am guessing that my original install had failed to check some sort of box with the needed styles.  I am not sure.

Second, once I did that, there were 3 styles available, not 2.  "windowsvista", "Windows" and "Fusion"